# How do I get Batch to choose a random number from 0 to 5?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

First of all, thank you for reading this.

I am making a fun little program in batch to practice with it and get familiar. I know this may not be the best language to start with, but it's what i'm using.

Here is what I have:

```
@echo off
:ask trump

set /p Input= Ask Trump Something (Yes or No questions):

goto random

:random
set /a "rand=%random% %% 6"
goto option%number%

cls

:option0
echo You asked: %Input% 
echo Trump: Covfefe
pause
goto ask trump

:option1
echo You asked: %Input%
echo Trump: I dont know, and I dont care.
pause
cls
goto ask trump

option2
echo You asked: %Input%
echo Trump: CHINA
pause
cls
goto ask trump

:option3
echo You asked: %Input%
echo Trump: Build a wall.
pause
cls
goto ask trump

:option4
echo You asked: %Input%
echo Trump: I think so, yes.
pause
cls
goto ask trump

:option5
echo You asked: %Input%
echo Trump: No, I don't think there's a chance.
pause
cls
goto ask trump
```

I want it so that It completely disregards what the user writes and just chooses a random answer. But, whenever I try it, I type in a question, hit enter, and it does nothing. Another input thing pops up without any new text, and it crashes no matter what I type in there. I have tried to find answers on here but I couldn't find something that would work/do what I wanted.

Again, I greatly appreciate any help and I apologize if I wasted your time.

Comment: Should be plain as day in these two lines of code. `set /a "rand=%random% %% 6"` and `goto option%number%`. If you would debug your batch file properly by running it from a cmd prompt and turning `echo on` you could see the error message plain as day.

Comment: @Squashman Thank you very much! I was foolish enough not to try that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is that you `set /a rand` but then you never use `rand` as a variable, instead you say `goto option%number%` which should be `goto option%rand%

Some other things I changed, added cls after `:ask trump` this way you get rid op the `c:\>` prompt and is left with a plain cmd screen.
cls was added to the rest of the tags as well so it will look a lot cleaner on screen.

Lastly, the line `set /a rand=%random% %%6` will generate a number set between `0 - 5` which is fine as it is 6 numbers regardless, but labelling your options based on real values sounds like a better idea. So if I have 6 answers I want to label them `1 - 6` instead of `0 - 5` therefore it is better to set the random as `set /a rand=%random% %%6 +1` The options were updated accordingly as well.

```
@echo off
:ask trump
cls
set /p Input= Ask Trump Something (Yes or No questions):

goto random

:random
set /a rand=%random% %%6 +1
goto option%rand%

:option1
cls
echo You asked: %Input% 
echo Trump: Covfefe
pause
goto ask trump

:option2
cls
echo You asked: %Input%
echo Trump: I dont know, and I dont care.
pause
cls
goto ask trump

:option3
cls
echo You asked: %Input%
echo Trump: CHINA
pause
cls
goto ask trump

:option4
cls
echo You asked: %Input%
echo Trump: Build a wall.
pause
cls
goto ask trump

:option5
cls
echo You asked: %Input%
echo Trump: I think so, yes.
pause
cls
goto ask trump

:option6
cls
echo You asked: %Input%
echo Trump: No, I don't think there's a chance.
pause
cls
goto ask trump
```