# How do I edit this matrix falling code and make it only binary?

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
title HELLO THERE!!!
color 04
echo This Matrix Affect was created by Craig The Psycho
echo This program will fry your computer's circuits!
echo The PSYCHO EFFECT begins in
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1>nul
echo 5
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1>nul
echo 4
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1>nul
echo 3
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1>nul
echo 2
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1>nul
echo 1

:superman
echo %random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%
goto superman
```

When I run this file, it displays every number, but I want it to be just 1's and 0's. Anyone think they can help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get Batch to choose a random number from 0 to 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47318761/how-do-i-get-batch-to-choose-a-random-number-from-0-to-5) (Except instead of `set /a rand=%random%%%6` it would be `set /a rand=%random%%%2`.)

Comment: I wonder if Craig the Psycho is aware that this code will not really _"Fry"_ any circuits.... Jokes aside `timeout /t 5` is a  much simpler than all those `ping` and `echo` commands.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop and set random numbers for 0 and 1 only using.

```
:superman
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%i in (1,1,40) do (
  set /a x=!random! %% 2
  set line=!line!!x!
)
echo %line% 
endlocal
goto superman
```